# How does iOS handle local Notification in background mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

`didReceiveLocalNotification` is called when a notification is fired in active mode but how does iOS handles notification in background mode (not active mode, application is terminated may be) before app is active by swiping or clicking the notification.

Or

Mainly I want to know how to conditionally handle local notification to be on/off (off means not to cancel previous notification but just don't fire it) in background Mode?

I am currently checking this condition in `didReceiveLocalNotification` but that way I am not able to handle it in background mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can check that is your app started by clicking on local notification in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate.m` file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif)
    {
       // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If application is running Alerts won't be shown automatically - you have to handle that manually using the functions you mentioned.

When application is in background or not running iOS will show your local notifications in notifications center and present them according to user settings - as a banner or alert.

Best read this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

When your app is in the background iOS will handle the notification (Local or Push) and your app can not access them at all.

Only after your app is started will you be able to direct if the user select a notification.